# Is it possible to cheat UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I would like to have a native scrolling experience in my iOS app from UIScrollView. But my app works on the different engine so I need to manipulate engine's objects instead of UIKit objects.

Is it possible to get the scrolling events from the UIScrollView without adding it to the view hierarchy?

I'm trying to delegate the touch events to the instance of UIScrollView and responding to the scrollViewDidScroll: but it doesn't work.

Is there any suggestion on how to initialize UIScrollView to make it think that it's in the hierarchy and make it work?

Comment: In what sense does scrollViewDidScoll: not work? You get the wrong numbers or the scroll view isn't scrolling at all or something else?

Comment: I dont't get any calls of scrollViewDidScroll: at all.

Answer (score 0):

The scrollViewDidScroll: event is raised when a user scrolls when a scrollview is on the screen. If the scrollview is never on the screen, then these events can never be raised.

Comment: I just don't want to add UIScrollView to the hierarchy because it conflicts with the engine display mechanic. So I'm trying to make it the opposite way: to let scroll view giving updates on content offset without being actually on screen. Any suggestion on that approach?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to cheat any control is going to get you into trouble. It won't be worth it!

Im not sure what engine you are using. Can you not get this engine to add its view to a subview of UIScrollView?

Failing that you can use [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to roll your own scrolling functionality.